# How to show base64 image in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, base64

I am storing the image in a base64 format in a node. Then I am receiving it and storing in a variable. and show it in the tag but it is not showing. Correct values are receiving from server. In render, function condition is true if the state is set.even if its true its not showing.

```
getImage() {
    console.log('getImage');
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/image/get`).then((result) => {
        this.setState({ image: result })
        console.log(result);
    });
}

render(){
    {this.state.image ? <img src={this.state.image}></img>: ''}
}
```

I am getting exact base64 string which i am storing in the server.It returns

```
<img src="[object Object]">
```

in DOM.I don't know where am I going wrong

**EDIT**

```
router.route('/image/get').get((req, res) => {
    console.log('inside img get');
    Image.find((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ "error": true, "message": "error fetching data" });
        } else {
            // console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
        }
    })

});
```

model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var ImageSchema=new Schema({
    imageName:{
        type:String
    },
    imageData:{
        type:String
    }

});

export default mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

Answer (score 31):

Did you make sure to add the encoding type in the src attribute along with the base64 encoded value?

```
render(){
    {this.state.image ? <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`}/>: ''}
}
```

Comment: tried. nothing showed up.it returns <img src="[object Object]">. the value in this.state.image  is    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN......."

Comment: @Krazy the thing is that the *src* of the actual image might be nested in the response *object*

Answer (score 4):

```
const byteCharacters = atob(result);
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

let image = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
```

Once you have the Blob you need to convert that into a data url like this:

```
let imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image);
this.setState({image: imageUrl});
```

now u can use this url saved in your state as a source for image like this:

```
<img src={this.state.image} />
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: not working.I am getting exact base64 string from server.

Comment: @Karthi i have edited the answer. try that and let me know. Also check the content-type that i am using to create blob is for jpeg image. You can use png or jpg instead of jpeg to suit your case.

Comment: return error :Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

Comment: Can you give me your api which returns this result?

Comment: i think there might be issue with the file that you are sending from your backend.

Comment: For getting base64 string  I am doing  result.data[0].imageData.so that I am getting only base64 string of that image.I am receiving exact base64 .but in dom its [object object]

Comment: then, this might be  on the level of extraction from the result object. Try some combinations with one level less filtering.

Comment: I didn't get what you said

Comment: what i meant is check if wrapping your imageData into an array (or extracting it out from array if it is already wrapped) before sending it works!

Comment: I was looking a for a solution too long to admit, this did it for me. where I recieve a base64 encoded image which I wanted to display in a <img>

Answer (score 2):

When you get this error:

```
<img src="[object Object]">
```

this means you insert an object to the src instead of a string.
my guess is that your response returns an object and not string

```
 axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/image/get`).then((result) => {
        this.setState({ image: result })
        console.log(result);
    });
```

check if the result is an object

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by matias bustos works correctly only just that you need to add `height` and `width` to the image tag like this:

```
render(){
   {this.state.image ? 
      <img width='500' height='200' src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`}/>: 
   ''}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly append base64 string to image source. First you have to decode it using Buffer then append that data in the src.

Try like this.

```
decodeBase64(base64data) {
    let base64ToString = Buffer.from(base64data, "base64").toString()
    this.setState({data: base64ToString })
}

render() {
    return (
       <img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.state.data} />
    )
}
```

**base64data is the data in base64 format.**

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Hi @PriyenMehta, Could you please ping the error here.

Comment: Thanks, But i solved it in different  way.