# How do I update the "src" of a React component and display a Base64 object as an image in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, bufferedimage, react-functional-component

I'm (relatively) new to software dev and am stuck with trying to display a Base64 Binary image in a React component.

Problem: I'm ultimately trying to display a Buffer JPEG Image in an`<img />` tag with a React component.

Using screenshot-desktop npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop) to capture desktop.

screenshot() returns a Promise which exposes a Buffer JPEG object.

Based on numerous posts, I have tried to convert this to a Base64 format and then update state so that I can subsequently access the Base64 image to include as a src in the image tag.

Here are the key parts of my code:-

```
const screenshot = require("screenshot-desktop");

function ScreenCapturer(props) {

  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  function captureCurrentScreen() {
    screenshot().then((bufferedImage) => {
      let base64Image = btoa(bufferedImage);
      setImage(base64Image);
    });
  }


  return (
    <div >

      <img className="image-holder" alt="" src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`}/>

      <h3>Image Capturer</h3>

      <h4>Base64Image : {image.substring(1, 20)}</h4>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          captureCurrentScreen();
        }}
      >
        Capture
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Key Issues:-

1. With the above code, I realise that the initial `src` value won't display anything.
2. On clicking the button, I'm able to display the first 20 characters of the Base64 image, so I  believe that the conversion process is working. After pressing the button, no image is shown nor is there any error shown.
3. Note: On checking devTools in the chrome Bowser, the object that screenshot() produces is stated as "Uint8 array"

Question: My understanding is that the component should re-render on setting a new state. Where am I going wrong ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe btoa() is what you want. That will try to convert your binary to ascii text: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_btoa.asp

I found these questions and answers that just put the base64 data into the image, like you're doing, directly from the source.
[convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)
[How to show base64 image in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769076/how-to-show-base64-image-in-react)

Those answers may point you in the right direction. If not, there are several npm modules around displaying base64 images. They may be able to solve it for you. https://npms.io/search?q=convert-image-base64

Answer (score 0):

If the image is of type file you can maybe try to use [URL.createObjectURL(yourData)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
It takes a type file or blob as input and sends a temporary URL.
So to convert a uint8 array into a blob you can try `new Blob([bufferedImage])`

Code:

```
const blob = new Blob([bufferImage]);
const tempUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
setImage(tempUrl)
/// ...
<img src={tempUrl} />
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Hit an initial snag with VS code filling in ```URL.createObjectUrl``` (which is not recognised as a function). Correct syntax is ```URL.createObjectURL``` (as you pointed out !). Works a treat.

Comment: Yes my bad, I just edited the code : ). Good to hear it worked out for you