# How to show a base64 image in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks

I get some information from the API that has a property called **pic** (image) which is base64
like this:

```
{description: "description"
id: 1
isActive: false
max: 10
min: 1 
pic: "W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ=="   //-->is base64
rewardCategoryEnTitle: "test"
rewardCategoryId: 2
rewardCategoryTitle: "test"
scoreValue: 200
title: "test"}
```

How can I show it in tag `<img/>`?

Comment: Your `W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ==` doesn't look like a valid base64 img.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show base64 image in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769076/how-to-show-base64-image-in-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769076/how-to-show-base64-image-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is include `data:image/jpg;base64,` infront of the base64 string. You can change jpg to whatever file type you want it to be

```html
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,....."/>
```

so if you are using react it would probably be like this

```js
<img src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${objectName.pic}`}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is valid base64 you can show it like this

```
<img class="itemImage" src="{{ 'data:image/png;base64,' + photo }}"/>
```

Validate your base64 string [here](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).